# Lucene MultiFieldQueryParser and Highlighter

Tags: lucene, query-parser, lucene-highlighter, fast-vector-highlighter

I am indexing articles in lucene index through different fields i.e. `title`, `description`, `link`, `publishDate`

I query the index using **MultiFieldQueryParser** like

```
+(title:[text]^5.0 description:[text]^4.0 link:[text]^3.0) +publishDate:[20150101 TO 20150531]
```

and then i show the articles as the search results.
So far all is good.
Now I want to highlight the search text in the title,description

How shall i go about this?
The normal **Highlighter** gives me **NullPointerException** while generrating fragments.
and **PostingHighlighter** gives me a `Map` with results grouped together according to the field.. but i don't want it that way. I was the entire document to be returned together with highlighting of search text in title and description.

Any help or suggestion or code snippet is appreciated..

Comment: Post your Highlighter code so we can see what you're missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using the `FieldType` for all the fields that I wanted highlighted:

```
FieldType ft = new FieldType();
ft.setIndexed(true);         
ft.setIndexOptionsFieldInfo.IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
ft.setStored(true);
ft.setStoreTermVectors(true);
ft.setStoreTermVectorOffsets(true);
ft.setTokenized(true);
ft.stored();

QueryScorer qs = new QueryScorer(q);
Highlighter h = new Highlighter(qs);
highlighter.setTextFragmenter(new SimpleFragmenter(300));           
String highlighted = h.getBestFragment(new StandardAnalyzer(),f,Text);
```